# How do I can run tests in MacOsX with Visual Studio 2017 and NUnit 3?

Tags: visual-studio, nunit-3.0

I recently installed Visual Studio Community 2017 on my Mac and every works perfectly except when I go to run my tests written with NUnit3 framework. I already installed the NUnit3TestAdapter package and when I press the option to run a test the only message that I get is Build successful.

Comment: This will be a .NET Core/.NET Standard project, right? Are you using the (pre-release) 3.8-alpha version of the NUnit3TestAdapter? (https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/3.8.0-alpha1) That's the first version with .NET Core support. I don't know if it's been tested with VS for Mac though - let us know how it goes!

Comment: Yes it is a .Net Core project and the version that I am using of NUnit3TestAdapter it is the 3.7.0

Comment: You need to use the `3.8.0-alpha1` version instead. Make sure you check the 'include pre-releases' checkbox, so you can see it. Microsoft changed the .NET Core test adapter format between VS 2015 and 2017, and this is the first version of the NUnit Test adapter which supports the new format.

Comment: I updated the package to 3.8.0-alpha1 but the result is the same

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I can run the tests in Rider but in Visual studio for mac I have no test to run: "No test is available in ..."

Comment: No, I don't, I moved to windows until the environment gets more stable I was having issues with the debugger as well, that is to much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recent NUnit version resolves this issue. With NUnit `3.9.0` and NUnit3TestAdapter `3.9.0`, it works fine.